What is friend injection in C++?
I've managed to find plenty of material on different topics about friend injection:

Will friend injections be
ill-formed?
ADL and friend
injection
Requires clause and friend injection

... except an explanation on what exactly friend injection is. Can someone clear things up?

I did not find plenty material so I am not even sure what exactly you mean with "friend injection". If you need help understanding some offsite material you should include the relevant parts here.

It doesn't exist in standard C++. The standard draft (pre-ratification in 1998) specified that when templates are instantiated, they produce function declaration of friends, into the enclosing scope. The concept was problematic, and the rules were changed to just have ADL consider them.  Here's the paper with the change to ADL https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0777.pdf.

So it was removed in 1995? Then we can probably forget about it.  :-)

One small correction since I thought I was linking another paper (which now eludes me). The paper I link discusses the problem with injection. It does not in fact suggest hiding inline friends and changing ADL. The solution it proposed was quite different, and not accepted.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm not even sure about the exact term. Perhaps it may be also known as a friend name injection. I only know it has to do something with friends within a class (template?) scope. Just googling it gives me plenty of friend injection here and there except a mere answer on what this so called friend injection is.

I suppose this could make an interesting question. I already learned something. Though, honestly, the phrasing is somewhat wonky as its very unclear what "plenty material" you refer to. Where have you gotten the term from? Perhaps refering to one concrete source would already clear things up a lot.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai here are some SO links I get among the first results for the C++ friend injection search request: Will friend injections be ill-formed? ADL and friend injection

If I understand what you are looking for, there is a good, but possibly tangential, example in Overloading friend operator<< for class template

I also got some google hits, but I am suggesting you to [edit] one (or more) references (possibly with relevant quotes) into your question in the hope this would make your question more focused and more answerable.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I've added some links, but the question is already closed. Guess I'm doomed never to find out what this mysterious friend injection is...

a common misconception. Getting a question closed is part of how this site works. Reopening as well.

You'd have better luck searching for "hidden friends lookup in templates". Seems "friend injection" is used colloquially to refer to that. Not stellar, since the prehistoric behavior also used similar terms.

I checked the Q&As you link. They seem to assume the reader know what they are talking about and then go into discussing details. Someone more knowledgebale than me might find a different Q&A that is more basic and could make a duplicate, until then I vote to reopen.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica could you please upvote to reopen the question? I've added some links which make it clear the term does exist and needs to get clarified.

Eh, It doesn't really exist. I can see why it'd be confusing, since some people repurposed the name of an old behavior to describe the new one. But the fact you had to actually show where you read it so that experts can tell you what it meant from context doesn't give it much weight. It's like "fancy pointer" (a less used term for smart pointers).

Maybe, but if hidden friends lookup in templates is the proper term, then I haven't ever heard of it, whereas this friend injection is here and there from time to time. And this is not the case with fancy pointers as the proper term smart pointers is quite widespread. Still, this may only be so from my own perspective, and not from anyone else's.

I only heard the term "friend injection" in the context of "compile-time/constexpr counter" and "stateful metaprogramming" so far. See e.g. https://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/ and https://mc-deltat.github.io/articles/stateful-metaprogramming-cpp20 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082260/c-compile-time-counters-revisited. AFAIK this is also the "loophole" thing in boost.pfr used in C++14 mode.
